# Using boundp with a symbol generated in a macro

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write the following code:

```
(unless (boundp 'foo-1)
(setq foo-1 bar-1))
(find-file foo-1)
```

However, the symbols foo-1 and bar-1 should be generated via a macro.  I tried something like the following, but it looks like `boundp` is not functioning the way I want.  I am not very experienced with macros; am I doing something obviously wrong?  Also, am I  abusing macros here?..

```
(defmacro foo-setq-bar (X)
  `(setq ,(intern (concat "foo-" (number-to-string X))) (assign-bar-to-foo ,X)))
(defmacro foo-find-file (X)
  `(progn
     (unless (boundp (quote ,(intern (concat "foo-" (number-to-string X)))))
       (foo-setq-bar ,X))
     (find-file ,(intern (concat "foo-" (number-to-string X))))))
```

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong, but there's a chance your code is more complicated than necessary. Give full code (you're missing a definition of `assign-bar-to-foo`) and an example of something that goes wrong (“I want `(some expression)` to have (some effect) but instead it (has some other effect)”). If you explain your higher-level problem, maybe someone can suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided seems to run fine, although you didn't provide the code for `assign-bar-to-foo` so it's not clear what that does. In any case, this is a macro that should do what you explained in your example:

```
(defmacro find-foobar (X)
  (let* ((X-as-string (number-to-string X))
         (foo (intern (concat "foo-" X-as-string)))                  
         (bar (intern (concat "bar-" X-as-string))))          
  `(progn (unless (boundp (quote ,foo))             
            (setq ,foo ,bar))
          (find-file ,foo))))
```

Remember that you can check the code your macro expands to with `(macroexpand FORM)`.